# Stuck at Smith normal form

Tags: matrices

Can somebody help me with the Smith normal form of this matrix? I know what it should be, but I get stuck at some point. Can you show how to take it from the point I'm stuck?

This is the matrix:

[original matrix http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/661/KhsK4K.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/661/KhsK4K.png)

And this is the point where I'm stuck:

[second matrix http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/909/iOfRTG.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/150x100q90/909/iOfRTG.png)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding out the brackets, we have

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & x^{2}-8x+16 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{2}-3x+2
\end{pmatrix}

Now add row 4 to row 3 to get

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & x^{2}-8x+16 & x^{2}-3x+2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{2}-3x+2
\end{pmatrix}

Subtract column 3 from column 4 to get an entry of lower degree:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & x^{2}-8x+16 & 5x-14 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & x^{2}-3x+2
\end{pmatrix}

Swap columns 3 and 4:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 5x-14 & x^{2}-8x+16 \\ 
0 & 0 & x^{2}-3x+2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

I think if you got this far, you should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I think starting with that comes the hard part. I will struggle more!

Comment: Ok, I did it. Thank you very much again!